# How do I handle a standard .then style callback in clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

Suppose I wanted to ask something of the browser, like this JS example:

```
if (navigator.requestMIDIAccess) {
  console.log('WebMIDI is supported in this browser.');
  navigator.requestMIDIAccess().then(onMIDISuccess, onMIDIFailure);
```

How would I do that in ClojureScript? I see some examples for AJAX style web requests, and some really complicated scenarios, and so on, but what is the simplest route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (navigator.requestMIDIAccess) {
  console.log('WebMIDI is supported in this browser.');
  navigator.requestMIDIAccess().then(onMIDISuccess, onMIDIFailure);
}
```

Simply translates too:

```
(when (.-requestMIDIAccess navigator)
  (.log js/console "WebMIDI is supported in this browser.")
  (.then (.requestMIDIAccess navigator) on-midi-success on-midi-failure))
```

Where `on-midi-success` and `on-midi-failure` are some function you defined prior to handle the promise being fulfilled or rejected.

So basically `.then` style callbacks are handled exactly the same in ClojureScript as they are in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You have various options: `then` is just a function, so you can just use `(.then ..`).
If the `then`able is a Promise object, promesa https://cljdoc.org/d/funcool/promesa/5.1.0/doc/user-guide has a nice interop story.

It's also pretty simple to add some macro syntax sugar around promises, as I've done here:
https://gist.github.com/beders/06eeb1d8f49de715c6bd2b84f634cff6

Comment: I am deeply appreciative of the answer! I'm also blown away that ClojureScript has such complex solutions to what is a one-liner in JS... and a very, very common one-liner.

Comment: Complex? Actually promesa makes things *simpler* not complex.
A simple `then` is a one-liner in any case. 
Things get more interesting, if you need to coordinate - in parallel - several async calls.
That's where promesa is pretty sweet

Comment: What is especially nice: In CLJS, these are *libraries*, not new language features like await/async - which - in essence - is syntactic sugar over promises.

Comment: OK... I'll take a look at promesa. The problem is me, I'm sure... a look at the promesa documentation was a bit overwhelming due the possible scenarios and options, but I'll figure it out, I guess.

Comment: you can just call (.then ...) as you would with JavaScript

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong... but this in fact did work in the end.

Comment: And then... somehow stopped working. Weird. The Promesa documentation is baffling to me, unfortunately.